# JS - Confusion on function that rewrite tyself

Tags: javascript, jquery

To all JS experts,
Im still trying to learn JS using books from **Stoyan Stefanov (Object-Oriented JS).**

Get stuck on **page 83**, where the following codes must work,

```js
a = a(); // First Call
function a() {
 alert('A');
 a = function() { // I get this. Redefining functions.
  alert('B');
 };
}
a(); // Second Call
```

The book suggested that if we **call/invoke for the 2nd time** it would actually **alert B** after alert A occur.

However, instead of working it gives us **TypeError: a is not a function** after successfully alert A.

Whats the mistake here??

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line:

```
a = a();
```

calls the function and assigns its return value to `a`. But the function's return value is `undefined` - any function that doesn't explicitly return a value with `return` will implicitly return `undefined` (unless called with `new`, but you can ignore that here). So then on the last line when you say `a()` you are basically saying `undefined()`. And of course `undefined` is not a function.

Did the code in the book really say `a = a();`? Change it to `a()` and it'll work as expected.

Alternatively you could change the function to return the new function on the first call rather than overwriting `a` directly:

```
a = a(); // First Call
function a() {
 alert('A');
 // following line changed to return the new function instead
 // of assigning it to a immediately
 return function() { 
  alert('B');
 };
}
a(); // Second Call
```

Comment: so the correct thing should be `return function() {alert('B')}` instead of that. So mistakes from the books??

Comment: Yes, returning the function like that would work with `a = a()`. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: you should also read up about function hoisting. this is happening here and should be noted

Answer (score 0):

When you do a first call

```
a = a(); // First Call
```

you assign function result to your variable a. Yet your a() does not return anything. So, on a second attempt, a is `undefined`.

Changing first line to just `a()` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how the naming of variables and functions and their scope is important in JavaScript.  Consider the following code...

```
a = a();
console.log('typeof global variable a :',(typeof a));
function a() {
     console.log('A');
     a = function() {
         console.log('B');
     };
     console.log('typeof global function a() inner function a() :',(typeof a));
}
console.log('typeof global function a() :',(typeof a));
a();

//=> ! TypeError: a is not a function
//=> A
//=> typeof global function a() inner function a() : function
//=> typeof global variable a : undefined
//=> typeof global function a() : undefined
```

So what's going on?

The inner variable `a` of the `function a()` returns its type : `function`

The global variable `a` is set to the return value of `function a()` - but the function doesn't return anything so it automatically becomes `undefined`

The type of global `function a()` is still determined by the value `a` 'outside' of itself (so to speak) - `undefined`

Notice the order in which the calls to `console.log()` arrive in?

Not only is the inner `a` not set with `var`, automatically placing it within the global scope, but `a = a()` means it is no longer even a function!

It is `a = a()` which causes the `a is not a function` TypeError.

On the other hand, look what happens when I remove `a =` but leave everything else as it was...

```
a();
console.log('typeof global variable a :',(typeof a));
function a() {
     console.log('A');
     a = function() {
         console.log('B');
     };
     console.log('typeof global function a() inner function a() :',(typeof a));
}
console.log('typeof global function a() :',(typeof a));
a();

//=> A
//=> typeof global function a() inner function a() : function
//=> typeof global function a() : function
//=> typeof global variable a : function
//=> B
```

See how the order has changed?

We can't think of 'global variable a' (as it was before) as a variable now - the `a` is just a token which points to the function.

`function a()` is called, fires the `console.log(`A`)`, resets the token `a` (which is itself) to the new function, and then fires the `console.log(`B`)` when called again.

There's a bit more detail that can be squeezed out of this, and better ways of achieving the same result, but the calls to the console are a big clue to what's going on.  Don't think of the example as a usable pattern - think of it as something which hints at how a JavaScript engine goes about doing what it does.

You might find this article from JavaScriptIsSexy.com useful: [JavaScript Variable Scope and Hoisting Explained](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. By the way you mention about usable pattern, any good books you recomend to learn latest pattern for javascript application??